Tilting modules for quantum groups in non-regular blocks
Let $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ denote Lusztig's quantum group associated to $\mathfrak{g}$ and $q$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ and $q \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a root of unity of order $>2$. Let $Tilt(U_q(\mathfrak{g})) \subset $Rep($U_q(\mathfrak{g}))$ denote the subcategory of tilting modules.
Riche and Williamson have given an explicit construction of a graded refinement of the full subcategory of $Tilt(U_q(\mathfrak{g}))$ consisting of the modules in the principal block (see Theorem 1.2 here) and the question is whether there exists a similar desciption of tilting modules in other (non-regular) blocks.
I am aware that multiplicity formulas for non-regular blocks can be derived from the regular case and I am really looking for a graded refinement of the category. Is it reasonable to expect such a category to exist, and if so, is a construction already known?
